# Box api-content developer account to production ready account

Tags: box-api

I currently have a developer account setup in box and looking for steps to move it to production. I cannot find details on 
  If there is number of users allowed
  How to turn production mode on

I am have setup initial account with auth redirect url. Configured my app key and token in my web application.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of "productizing" I've heard a few different ways this term

1) To just make an app generally useable among consumers of the third party app, all that is needed is a functional integration with Box APIs. Assuming that you have implemented oAuth correctly and integrated our APIs functionally, there is no barrier to everyday users to using that integration between Box + third party app.

2) To make an app available to Box users ("productionalize" is a term I hear often), the best way to do this is through our gallery. Developers can follow these instructions for creating a listing in our App Gallery: cloud.box.com/appgallerylisting